# Why is riemann zeta function non-elementary?

Tags: calculus, elementary-functions

Why are functions like ln(x), sin(x), cos(x) etc. considered elementary functions but something like the Riemann Zeta function isn't?

All of them can be defined as an infinite series. What makes a function elementary vs non-elementary?

Comment: The function $f : (-1,1) \to \Bbb{R}$, $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ can also be defined through an infinite series, 

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} x^k$$

so I don't think that is the relevant criterion. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) chooses to claim that they're "sums, products, and compositions of finitely many polynomial, rational, trigonometric, hyperbolic, and exponential functions, including possibly their inverse functions"

Comment: Someone edit the original question which was a bit more "wide", but I think is a mix about technical ease to obtain with their historical importance as it where rising among mathematicians... actually are some definitions to separate different functions through its "complexity": [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Comparison_of_different_classes_of_expressions)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I'm not saying that a function defined through an infinite series necessarily makes it elementary; I was just using that fact to compare the mentioned functions. My question basically is why are the criteria for elementary functions the way they are?
For example, the integral of (-log(1 - x)/x) dx which is defined to be Li_2(x) is considered non-elementary. However, the integral of 1/x dx is defined to be ln(x) which is elementary. I don't think these functions are fundamentally all that different.

Comment: That trigonometric and logarithm functions are "elementary" is deeply connected to the fact that $\exp(z)$ is an homomorphism $\Bbb{C\to C^\times}$.